# Getting all time speaker enable and on headphone speaker working fine?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio-route

```
UInt32 audioRouteOverride = enabled ? kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker : kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_None;

if(AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute, sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride) == 0){
    speakerOn = enabled;
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: please describe your problem in detail

Comment: hey @originaluser2 my question is ...... when i am getting video call that time loudspeaker enable and after click on speaker button to disable the loudspeaker this is not happening

Comment: please edit the OP and describe your problem - not in the comments